# Need to get contacts from long list of custom ids

Tags: soql, reporting

I have a long list (few thousand) of custom IDs in salesforce, I have been asked to provide contacts for all off the corresponding ids. The ids are on the account object.

My initial thought was to Query for example.

```
SELECT Id, Name, ( SELECT Name, Email, FROM Contacts )
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Debtorid__C = '001','002',........
```

However this seems long and cumbersome is there an easier more efficient way?

I would Ideally like the results in a spread sheet.

thank-you for your help

Comment: In workbench create the query and then in the end add all Id value and fetch the record in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SOQL query in dataloader (at least with [dataloader.io](http://dataloader.io). This will allow you to save the results in a spreadsheet. I would make the query on `Contact`:

```
SELECT Name, Email
FROM Contact
WHERE Account.Debtorid__c IN ('001', '002', 'etc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a field on Account name say "Extract", use a CSV with the IDs you have to make Extract__c true. The you can run a report on accounts and contacts where Extract__c on the account = true.

You can also use data loader to extract all contacts where Account.Extract__r = true.